# Drawing flat shapes on HTML canvas creates blurry borders

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to draw flat shapes, like rectangles, on an HTML canvas but whenever I use the `fillRect` or `rect` and then `fill`, the outcome is a shape with some kind of blurry inner glow and shadow. Is there any way to get rid of these “light effects”?

As an example, here’s a piece of code I used:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('map');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = c;
ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
```

and the produced outcome (with the glow and shadow):

[image: outcome]

Comment: How did you get the image you linked to. If it is via screen capture it does not help as the artifacts are unlike any you would get with normal rendering. Check that the canvas.style width and hieght atrributes match the canvas width and height. If they do not match then you will see more pronounced  antialias artifacts. Ensure when rendering that you render at pixel boundaries, rendering at x = 1.5, y= 1.5 will have a different look than x = 1 and y = 1 as you would be rendering mid way on a pixel

Comment: On top of what Blindman67 said, try `x=parseInt(x)+0.50;
  y=parseInt(y)+0.50;`.

Comment: Thank you! It seems the problem really was I hadn't set the width and height attributes... Thank you all for this support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably just set the canvas.width and canvas.height to the same values you got the css style.
when some elements get scaled by css they normally get antialias (canvas and images).

```
image-rendering: auto;
image-rendering: crisp-edges;
image-rendering: pixelated;
```

some browsers also comply with these styles that remove the antialias 
 more about the css [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/)

Answer (score -1):

I use another method for drawing shapes:

```
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var rectX = 400, rectY = 300;

function draw() {
context.fillStyle = "#FFFF00"
context.fillRect(rectX, rectY, 100, 200);
}

draw();
```

Here's a fiddle with the result:
https://jsfiddle.net/Sufi2425/fnd5es9a/